# Insert JSON data into MongoDB using mongoengine and python without reordering the JSON

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongoengine

Please help me to insert JSON data without re-ordering into mongoDB using python and mongoengine.

My JSON data:

```
 {
 "x":"y",
 "z":"t",
 "q":{"a":"b"}
}
```

It stores as ,

```
{
 "z":"t",
 "q":{"a":"b"},
 "x":"y"
}
```

I want to store the JSON as it is actually.....

Comment: Try using a OrderedDict

Comment: Still facing issue. .  OrderedDict also not working... I need to save the data into mongoDB as it is

Comment: Items in a JSON object have no order so what you want might be impossible.

Comment: @BlackJack What if you stored the json of OrderedDict as a string..

Comment: @SuhasK Storing a structured document into a database for such documents as a string representation seems a bit pointless. You lose the ability to query on the contents of the documents and that's usually why someone chooses such a database in the first place.

Comment: @BlackJack So you store it twice. Once as a formatted string and the other as a normal json.